# Matplotlib colorbar: some ticks appear without labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm using plr.scatter and logariphmic scale, and i'm trying to add some specific tick values to the colorbar, but it seems to work really arbitrary. See the example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 30), np.linspace(0, 1, 30))
z = x**2 + 15*y**3 + 1.5
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4.5))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm.jet, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), vmin=1, vmax=20)
formatter = LogFormatter(10, labelOnlyBase=False) 
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=[1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20], format=formatter)
```

This code produced all the required major ticks, plus some minor ticks, but only labeled 1 and 10, while I need all numbers to be seen in colorbar. At first I though it was due to the fact that 1 and 10 are integer powers of 10, and other number are not, but...

[image]

...if I change the log base to 2, we can see tick labels at 1 and 2, which are powers of 2, but we also see labels at 5, 10 and 20, which are not. 15 did not appear this time too, but if I try adding 17 it works (not shown on the picture, but it does)

```
formatter = LogFormatter(2, labelOnlyBase=False)
```

[image]

What is this sorcery and how do I make matplotlib add *exactly* the labels I want to the ticks? I can do it manually by using

```
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '5', '10', '15', '20'])
```

but it seems redundant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can format `any axis` ticks with `formatter`. Below is the example .

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 30), np.linspace(0, 1, 30))
z = x**2 + 15*y**3 + 1.5
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4.5))
p = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm.jet, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=20) )

v1 = np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), 8, endpoint=True)

cbar=plt.colorbar(ticks=v1)              
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["{:4.2f}".format(i) for i in v1]) # add the labels
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

[LogFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=logformatter#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter) and its subclasses use the `minor_thresholds` parameter to decide when to hide non-decade tick labels to prevent overcrowding. By default this will hide nearly all non-decade labels, but you can increase it to allow more labels to appear.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 30), np.linspace(0, 1, 30))
z = x**2 + 15*y**3 + 1.5

cnorm = LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=20)
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4.5))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm.jet, norm=cnorm)

# define minor_thresholds to be >= the range of the color scale
decades = np.ceil(np.log10(cnorm.vmax / cnorm.vmin))
formatter = LogFormatter(10, minor_thresholds=(decades, decades))

cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=[1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20], format=formatter)
```

[image: scatter plot of rainbow dots, similar to original post but the colorbar is labeled at every explicitly defined tick value]